# When is std::initializer_list trivially constructible?

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list

In my opinion, I think when the objects of type `Ts...` used to initialize `std::initializer_list<T>` can be used to construct `T` trivially, then `std::initializer_list<T>` is trivially constructible from `Ts...` because according to [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), each element of `std::initializer_list<T>` is either `direct_initialized` or `copy_initialized`.

However, I'm not sure whether I'm right, so I posted this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question itself does not make sense. That is, you are asking about the presence of a property for an operation for which the property simply doesn't apply.

The 6 special member functions (default constructor, copy/move constructor/assignment operator, and destructor) can be trivial. But these are the *only* things which can be trivial, for which the term "trivial" has a well-defined meaning.

List initialization isn't doing any of those. At least, not directly.

The process of list initializing an `initializer_list` involves the creation of a temporary array, putting the values from the braced-init-list into it, and creating an `initializer_list` that points to that array. None of these are operations for which triviality is even in question, so asking whether they are "trivial" doesn't make sense.